# Synchronize block methods that trigger networking calls in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a project that uses blocks pattern withCompletion to call a method

`[ClientApiServicesProvider shared] influencerService] getLikesListWithOffset:offset :self.isSearchRequest :self.searchKey WithCompletion:^(NSDictionary * _Nullable likes, NSError * _Nullable error)`

This method block is asynchronous and can be called by the user everytime he writes a new character in a textfield and every time a new character comes up it triggers a network call using NSURLSessionDataTask . These calls are asynchronous. I am calling the method above from my UIViewcontroller. Is there any way to cancel this network request before starting a new one? If there is no way what are the alternatives? I was thinking using @synchronized {} and put the above block method inside the brackets of @synchronized. Any help or ideas appreciated...

Comment: I don't fully understand what problem you are trying to address by synchronisation/request cancellation. Do you want to get rid of overhead, and you are interested in the latest result only or you need all results come in order?

Comment: Yes i need to get the latest result only. But i can not cancel somehow the previous block call Or network call so i am trying to find a way to synchronize the results. User calls this method lets say 5 times so i am doing 5 network calls but i do not know which of the five network results will return data back first...it might be the third call that returns data back first, but i need the network results of the fifth call to be the last i show to the user...

Comment: What about checking the values of `offset`, `searchKey` etc in the completion block to see if they are up to date? If not, you can discard the fetched data.

Comment: @Larme hmm nice idea but checking what exactly? If on the first request the offset is 0 and the searchkey is "a" and on the second request the searchkey is "ab" and the offset is 0 again what should i check on the completion block?

Comment: You are using an offset, so you are doing recursive calls? Also, you are badly naming your methods, there is no text before `:` the parameter. What do you do later with the results? Do you append them? How? What about returning in the completion block, `searchKey` to compare it with current `self.searchKey` (and discard if not the same)?

Comment: yes i append the data to a datalist NSMutableArray. This is the code i use   if(self.likes){
                if(offset==0){
                    self.likes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:model.data];
                }
                else{
                    [self.likes addObjectsFromArray:model.data];
                }
            }
            else{

                self.hashtags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:model.data];
            } ... i do not return or check the searchkey

Answer (score 1):

Most network APIs will have some means of cancelling them. In the case of `NSURLSession`, data tasks have a `-cancel` function (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/1411591-cancel). If you were using `NSURLSession`, in order to achieve the functionality you desire, you would have to hold on to the previously submitted data task and then cancel it when a new request is submitted.

You should find out how your function `-getLikesListWithOffset:WithCompletion:` makes calls to the network, and then appropriately hold on to previous requests in some manner so they can be potentially cancelled in the future. One way to do this might be returning a data task (in the case of `NSURLSession`) from this method and then relying on the caller to cancel the data task if they make future requests.

As an aside, you may want to look into using "debounce" logic (https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) in order to avoid making network requests over and over, every time the user taps a character.